# Is there any method to solve this problem using oracle SQL. Got stuck in this problem

Tags: sql, oracle

This image contains the detailed table and required output.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste the tables as formatted text into your request instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT combined,
       CASE WHEN '/' || combined || '/' LIKE '%/TD/%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS td,
       CASE WHEN '/' || combined || '/' LIKE '%/DEMAT/%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS demat,
       CASE WHEN '/' || combined || '/' LIKE '%/NR_PINS/%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS nr_pins,
       CASE WHEN '/' || combined || '/' LIKE '%/FOREX/%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS forex
FROM   table_name
```

*Note: you need to include the delimiters before and after the strings to match and being matched as, if you do not, you can match a partial item.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  combined VARCHAR2(50),
  td       NUMBER(1,0),
  demat    NUMBER(1,0),
  nr_pins  NUMBER(1,0),
  forex    NUMBER(1,0)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (combined)
SELECT 'TD/DEMAT/FOREX/NR_PINS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FOREX/NR_PINS/DEMAT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NR_PINS/MF/DEMAT/TD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NOT_TD/NOT_DEMAT/NOT_NR_PINS/NOT_FOREX' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COMBINED | TD | DEMAT | NR_PINS | FOREX |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | TD/DEMAT/FOREX/NR_PINS | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | FOREX/NR_PINS/DEMAT | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | NR_PINS/MF/DEMAT/TD | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
> | NOT_TD/NOT_DEMAT/NOT_NR_PINS/NOT_FOREX | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

---

If you want to update the table then you can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID as rid,
         CASE WHEN '/' || combined || '/' LIKE '%/TD/%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS td,
         CASE WHEN '/' || combined || '/' LIKE '%/DEMAT/%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS demat,
         CASE WHEN '/' || combined || '/' LIKE '%/NR_PINS/%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS nr_pins,
         CASE WHEN '/' || combined || '/' LIKE '%/FOREX/%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS forex
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET td = src.td,
      demat = src.demat,
      nr_pins = src.nr_pins,
      forex = src.forex;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=64a0cb3c315b36d98079a1361964e397)*

Comment: WHAT is "COMBINED" OVER HERE?

Comment: @PrabhakarKumarJha It is the name of the column with the raw data; it was taken directly from the image in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know all *separate* values (that make that *combined* string), a simple option might be conditional aggregation:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (combined) as
  2    (select 'TD/DEMAT/FOREX/NR_PINS' from dual union all
  3     select 'FOREX/NR_PINS/DEMAT'    from dual union all
  4     select 'NR_PINS/MF/DEMAT/TD'    from dual
  5    ),
```

Separate values:

```
  6  separate as
  7    (select 'TD' val  from dual union all
  8     select 'DEMAT'   from dual union all
  9     select 'NR_PINS' from dual union all
 10     select 'FOREX'   from dual
 11    )
```

Finally:

```
 12  select t.combined,
 13    max(case when s.val = 'TD'      and instr(t.combined, s.val) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) td,
 14    max(case when s.val = 'DEMAT'   and instr(t.combined, s.val) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) demat,
 15    max(case when s.val = 'NR_PINS' and instr(t.combined, s.val) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) nr_pins,
 16    max(case when s.val = 'FOREX'   and instr(t.combined, s.val) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) forex
 17  from test t cross join separate s
 18  group by t.combined;

COMBINED                       TD      DEMAT    NR_PINS      FOREX
---------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
FOREX/NR_PINS/DEMAT             0          1          1          1
TD/DEMAT/FOREX/NR_PINS          1          1          1          1
NR_PINS/MF/DEMAT/TD             1          1          1          0

SQL>
```

Comment: This will work as long as there isn't a search value which is a substring of another search value. It should be easy to control in the Seeker's scenario, because the search strings map to table columns (I think). It might not work in similar scenarios where the search strings aren't distinct.